# Side effects in Lisp/Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

My question is about structuring lisp code with side effects. The particular example I have in mind comes from Clojure, but I think it can apply to any lisp.

In this case, I am interacting with an existing library that requires some functions to be called in a particular order. The final function call creates the value I need for the rest of the procedure.

The code looks like this:

```
(defn foo [] 
    (let [_ procedure-with-side-effect
          __ another-procedure-with-side-effect
          value procedure-that-creates-the-value]
        (do-something value)))
```

This works and everything is great, except I think the let block looks hideous. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lisp every function body is a ordered set of forms. The value(s) of the last form will be returned. If the procedures don't use intermediate result values as arguments, a `LET` is not necessary. If the `procedure-that-creates-the-value` does not need to be documented by naming a variable, the `LET` binding for its value is also not necessary.

So in Lisp the code is just this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (procedure-with-side-effect)
  (another-procedure-with-side-effect)
  (do-something (procedure-that-creates-the-value)))
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need the intermediate values of the function calls, you can just put a bunch of function calls in the body of the `defn`:

```
(defn foo [] 
  (procedure-with-side-effect)
  (another-procedure-with-side-effect)
  (do-something (procedure-that-creates-the-value)))
```

While this is the best for this code, there are other options. You can also put any number of function calls in the body of a `let`:

```
(let [val 3]
     (fun-call-1)
     (fun-call-2)
     (fun-call-3 val))
```

And if you don't want to bind any values, you can use [`do`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28do%20exprs*%29):

```
(do (fun-call-1)
    (fun-call-2)
    (fun-call-3))
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not super experienced, but I'd do it this way:

```
(defn foo [] 
  (procedure-with-side-effect)
  (another-procedure-with-side-effect)
  (let [value (procedure-that-creates-the-value)]
    (do-something value)))
```

or

```
(defn foo [] 
  (procedure-with-side-effect)
  (another-procedure-with-side-effect)
  (-> (procedure-that-creates-the-value)
      do-something))
```

or

```
(defn foo [] 
  (procedure-with-side-effect)
  (another-procedure-with-side-effect)
  (do-something (procedure-that-creates-the-value)))
```

Edit: `defn` expressions are wrapped with an implicit `do`.